# Создание клиента к БД (WinForms\WPF)

Tags: c#

Через интерфес тот же WinForms хочу добалять какой-то товар или удалять, смотреть что осталось в базе.

Подскажите ссылку на ресурс или умную книжку, где есть описание с примером как создать подобный клиент к БД. Подойдёт и ресурс где это объясняется Джаверам/Плюсовикам.

Проект чисто учебный, основы Веб-сервисов и "Шарпа" имеются, читаю основы БД, просто хочу понять как это всё должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой, на мой взгляд, способ работы с БД - это [LINQ2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx).

Правильный способ - делать [3х уровневое приложение](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), где WPF/WinForms приложение будет обращаться к серверу (веб сервер, WCF или подобное), который будет уже работать с БД, но, возможно, для этой задачи это оверкилл.

Comment: Linq2SQL - это позавчерашний день тащемта

Comment: Но это самый простой способ познакомиться с ORM и с работой с бд.

Comment: а) чем конкретно он проще, нежели, скажем, EF?
б) вряд ли вообще можно навать хорошей идеей знакомство с бд через работу с ORM

Comment: в LINQ2SQL нет никаких лишних наворотов. Просто прямой байндинг к табличкам/процедурам, 1 к 1. Также он достаточно низкоуровневый, фактически это тонкая обертка над SQL. Те же запросы, только на шарпе. Для меня все сложности БД - это либо её проектирование (на что ОРМ совсем не влияет), либо оптимизация запросов (на что ей смотреть рано). Чем таким может навредить более красивый способ записи запросов?

Comment: LINQ не отменяет тот факт, что о вставке вам приходится заботиться самому, а также вручную настраивать binding к таблицам. EF позволяет от этого абстрагироваться.

Comment: @VladD, вручную - это мышкой из Server Explorer'а на dbml дизайнер перетянуть? 2 секунды "ручных настроек".